# C# xml reader, same element name

Tags: c#, xml, reader

I'm trying to read an element from my xml file.
I need to read an string in an "link" element inside the "metadata",
but there are 2 elements called "link", I only need the second one:

```
<metadata>
<name>visit-2015-02-18.gpx</name>
<desc>February 18, 2015. Corn</desc>
<author>
    <name>text</name>
    <link href="http://snow.traceup.com/me?id=397760"/>
</author>
<link href="http://snow.traceup.com/stats/u?uId=397760&amp;vId=1196854"/>
<keywords>Trace, text</keywords>
```

I need to read this line:

```
<link href="http://snow.traceup.com/stats/u?uId=397760&amp;vId=1196854"/>
```

This is the working code for the first "link" tag, it works fine,

```
        public string GetID(string path)
    {
        string id = "";
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "link"))
            {
                    if (reader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        id = reader.GetAttribute("href");
                        MessageBox.Show(id + "= first id");
                        return id;
                        //id = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    }
                }
            }
            return id;
        }
```

Does anyone know how I can skip the first "link" element?
or check if reader.ReadElementContentAsString() contains "Vid" or something like that?

I hope you can help me.

Comment: increment an int each time you read `link` int and ignore < 2?

Comment: Do you have to use XmlReader? If your xml structure is consistently in the format you provided, you could use XMLDocument and XPath to get the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [String.Contains method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if the string contains the desired substring, in this case `vId`:

```
public string GetID(string path)
{
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "link"))
        {
        if (reader.HasAttributes)
        {
            var id = reader.GetAttribute("href");
            if (id.Contains(@"&vId"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(id + "= correct id");
                return id;
            }
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

If acceptable you can also use [LINQ2XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
var reader = XDocument.Load(path); // or XDocument.Parse(path);
// take the outer link
Console.WriteLine(reader.Root.Element("link").Attribute("href").Value);
```

The output is always:

```
http://snow.traceup.com/stats/u?uId=397760&vId=1196854= first id
```

Another options is to use XPath like @user5507337 suggested.

Comment: thank you !
I tried it with contain but it didn't work, but I thinK I just made a mistake!
works perfect!

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

xpath is the answer :)

```
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("metadata/link");
        foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
             Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

XDocument example:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(path); //assuming path points to file
var nodes = xml.Root.Elements("link");
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
    var href = node.Attribute("href").Value;
}
```